Is it safe to assume 32-bit floats can be directly compared against each other if value fits the mantissa?
In a leetcode problem about finding if an integer number is sum of perfect squares, using floats instead of ints resulted in more speedup ("perfect-squares" problem). Is it safe to assume that if integer values are guaranteed to be less than 10000 and greater than or equal to 0, we can use floats instead?
Sample comparison:
if(n == i*i + j*j * 2)
    result3++;

if(n == i*i + k*k)
    result2++;

both int and float passed all tests (n,i,j,k, all float or all int) but I'm still not sure if there's any difference between CPUs (not sure if leetcode uses exact same always) or compiler or something else(like time?).
Link to problem and code: https://leetcode.com/problems/perfect-squares/description/
Code:
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
class Solution {
public:

static constexpr int simd =8;
using FAST_TYPE = short;
using MASK_TYPE = short;
    const int numSquares(const int n) const noexcept {
        if(n==2 || n==8)
            return 2;
        if(n==3 || n==6 || n==11)
            return 3;
        
        if((int)std::sqrt(n)*(int)std::sqrt(n) == n)
            return 1;

        FAST_TYPE found2 = 0;
        FAST_TYPE found3 = 0;
        FAST_TYPE found32 = 0;
        FAST_TYPE found33 = 0;
        FAST_TYPE found34 = 0;


        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE zeroSimd[simd];
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE oneSimd[simd];
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE found3Simd[simd];
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE found3Simd2[simd];
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE found3Simd3[simd];
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE found3Simd4[simd];                
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE mSimd[simd];
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE kSimd[simd];
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE k0Simd[simd];
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE nSimd[simd];
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE twoSimd[simd];
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE threeSimd[simd];   
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE iSimd[simd];     
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE jSimd[simd];
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE ijSimd[simd];           
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE j2Simd[simd];        
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE i2Simd[simd];      
        alignas(64)
        MASK_TYPE mask1Simd[simd];                    
        alignas(64)
        MASK_TYPE mask2Simd[simd];                    
        alignas(64)
        MASK_TYPE mask3Simd[simd];                    
        alignas(64)
        MASK_TYPE mask4Simd[simd];         
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE sum1Simd[simd];                                              
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE sum2Simd[simd];                                                      
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE sum3Simd[simd];       
        alignas(64)
        FAST_TYPE mulSimd[simd];                                                         
        for(int i=0;i<simd;i++)
        {
            zeroSimd[i]=0;
            oneSimd[i]=1;
            found3Simd[i]=0;
            found3Simd2[i]=0;
            found3Simd3[i]=0;
            found3Simd4[i]=0;
            mSimd[i]=i;
            nSimd[i]=n;
            twoSimd[i]=2;
            threeSimd[i]=2;
            
        }
        for(int i=1+std::sqrt(n);i>=1;i--)
        {
            const FAST_TYPE i2 = i*i;
            const FAST_TYPE i22 = 2*i*i;            
            const FAST_TYPE i23 = 3*i*i;            
            #pragma GCC ivdep
            for(int m=0;m<simd;m++)
                iSimd[m]=i2;
            #pragma GCC ivdep
            for(int m=0;m<simd;m++)
                i2Simd[m]=i22;                
            found2 += (i22 == n);            
            found3+=(i23 == n);   
            for(int j=i-1;j>=1;j--)
            {
                const FAST_TYPE j2 = j*j;
                const FAST_TYPE j22 = 2*j*j;
                const FAST_TYPE j23 = 3*j*j;
                #pragma GCC ivdep
                for(int m=0;m<simd;m++)
                    jSimd[m]=j2;
                #pragma GCC ivdep
                for(int m=0;m<simd;m++)
                    j2Simd[m]=j22;       
                #pragma GCC ivdep
                for(int m=0;m<simd;m++)
                    ijSimd[m]=i2+j2;                                      
                found2+=(i2 + j2 == n);
                found3+=(i2 + j22 == n)+(i22 + j2 == n)+(j23 == n);        
                const int k32 = j-1 - ((j-1)%simd);  
                #pragma GCC unroll 2
                for(int k0=1;k0<=k32;k0+=simd) 
                {
                    #pragma GCC ivdep
                    for(int m=0;m<simd;m++)
                        k0Simd[m]=k0;
                    #pragma GCC ivdep
                    for(int m=0;m<simd;m++)                 
                        kSimd[m] = k0Simd[m]+mSimd[m];
                    #pragma GCC ivdep
                    for(int m=0;m<simd;m++)                 
                        kSimd[m] = kSimd[m]*kSimd[m];


                    #pragma GCC ivdep
                    for(int m=0;m<simd;m++) 
                        sum1Simd[m]=ijSimd[m] + kSimd[m];
                    #pragma GCC ivdep
                    for(int m=0;m<simd;m++)                             
                        mask1Simd[m]=sum1Simd[m] == nSimd[m];
                    #pragma GCC ivdep
                    for(int m=0;m<simd;m++)                  
                        found3Simd[m]=mask1Simd[m]?oneSimd[m]:found3Simd[m];


                    #pragma GCC ivdep
                    for(int m=0;m<simd;m++) 
                        sum2Simd[m]=i2Simd[m] + kSimd[m];
                    #pragma GCC ivdep
                    for(int m=0;m<simd;m++)                             
                        mask2Simd[m]=(sum2Simd[m]==nSimd[m]);
                    #pragma GCC ivdep
                    for(int m=0;m<simd;m++)                  
                        found3Simd2[m]=mask2Simd[m]?oneSimd[m]:found3Simd2[m];

                    #pragma GCC ivdep
                    for(int m=0;m<simd;m++) 
                        sum3Simd[m]=j2Simd[m] + kSimd[m];
                    #pragma GCC ivdep
                    for(int m=0;m<simd;m++)                             
                        mask3Simd[m]=(sum3Simd[m]==nSimd[m]);                        
                     #pragma GCC ivdep
                    for(int m=0;m<simd;m++)                      
                        found3Simd3[m]=mask3Simd[m]?oneSimd[m]:found3Simd3[m];     


                    #pragma GCC ivdep
                    for(int m=0;m<simd;m++) 
                        mulSimd[m]=threeSimd[m]*kSimd[m];
                    #pragma GCC ivdep
                    for(int m=0;m<simd;m++)       
                        mask4Simd[m]=(mulSimd[m]==nSimd[m]);                    
                    #pragma GCC ivdep
                    for(int m=0;m<simd;m++)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                        found3Simd4[m]=mask4Simd[m]?oneSimd[m]:found3Simd4[m];
                    
                }

                
                for(int k=k32;k<=j-1;k++)   
                {                   
                    const FAST_TYPE k2 = k*k;
                    found3+=(i2 + j2 + k2 ==n);
                    found32+=(i22 + k2 ==n);
                    found33+=(j22 + k2 ==n);
                    found34+=(3*k2 ==n);
                }
            }      
        }

        for(int i=0;i<simd;i++)
        {
            found3+=found3Simd[i];
            found32+=found3Simd2[i];
            found33+=found3Simd3[i];
            found34+=found3Simd4[i];
        }
        found3 += found32 + found33 + found34;
        if(found2)
            return 2;

        if(found3)
            return 3;

        return 4;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Solution s;
    for(int i=10;i<20;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<i<<" is equal to sum of "<<s.numSquares(i)<< " perfect squares"<<std::endl; 
    }
}

output:
10 is equal to sum of 2 perfect squares
11 is equal to sum of 3 perfect squares
12 is equal to sum of 3 perfect squares
13 is equal to sum of 2 perfect squares
14 is equal to sum of 3 perfect squares
15 is equal to sum of 4 perfect squares
16 is equal to sum of 1 perfect squares
17 is equal to sum of 2 perfect squares
18 is equal to sum of 2 perfect squares
19 is equal to sum of 3 perfect squares


you can always compare floating point numbers directly via ==. Only if you assume floating point arithmetics to be exact issues arise. Your link to "problem and code" has no problem and no code and the code you posted here is incomplete. As example for the question its not very useful

also all the simd stuff seems to be unrelated

I think strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/how-do-you-compare-float-and-double-while-accounting-for-precision-loss . TL;DR you can't explicitly compare floating point numbers in the context of math problems, and the range [0, 1e5] is not very helpful, even simple 10*3 == 90/3 might not necessarily evaluate to true (there are better examples here in SO, I will try to find).

Updated code with a working example and direct link to problem. I don't know if simd was responsible or not for the float to work.

Potential reasons why float is faster in your case: 1. There is no sqrt(int) function, so the compiler converts to double for the function call, then back to short. If everything is float, it stays that way. 2. short is not a very fast data type unless vectorization actually works. The compiler likely sign-extends to int. 3. Most CPUs have only one integer multiplication unit (if not vectorized) but two floating point multiplicators.

It would be worth trying it in double precision since today on many CPUs double64 code is actually marginally faster than float32. 10^8 is also larger than the float32 mantissa of 23 bits = 2^23 = 8388608 ~ 8.4.10^6 can actually hold. You can safely compare integer values that fit into the mantissa as floats provided that you avoid division entirely and never overflow the available mantissa length. +,- and * are all safe provided that you do not overflow the available mantissa length. I suspect you will also find that it will run slightly faster if you make FAST_TYPE = int.

Side note: maybe the first time I see a question about Leetcode problem from a senior C++ programmer, not from a beginner wrongly believing he can learn the language that way.

@pptaszni There is no possible way that 10*3 == 90/3 could evaluate to false, floating point or not.  (90 * (1./3), that's another question.)

Contrary to popular belief, floating point arithmetic is exact, on the values it can represent.  Integers between 0 and 2²⁴ = 16777216 are exactly representable in single-precision floating point.

@MartinBrown There is an implicit 24'th bit of mantissa (achieved via normalization). So float can actually represent integers up to 2**24. Here is a quick proof: https://godbolt.org/z/Y5jM1bjzn


Is it safe to assume 32-bit floats can be directly compared against each other if value fits the mantissa?

This is not the right question; floating-point numbers can always compared with each other, and the comparison will indicate they are equal if and only iff they are equal.
The right question is whether using floating-point arithmetic will calculate the results you desire.
Per IEEE-754 and other floating-point specifications, each floating-point number represents one real number. That representation is exact, with no error. It is floating-point operations, not numbers, that approximate real arithmetic. When a floating-point operation is performed, the floating-point result is the real-number-arithmetic result rounded to the nearest value representable in the floating-point format (using a choice of rounding rules). If the real-number-arithmetic result is representable, it is the result; there will be no rounding.
The C++ standard guarantees float can represent numbers with enough resolution to distinguish six-significant-digit decimal numerals throughout its range. Therefore, it can represent all integers up to 1,000,000 at least, more than the 10,000 range you requested.
The operations you perform using integer values, such as 3*j*j, will be exact within this range.
This operation will not always be exact: (int)std::sqrt(n)*(int)std::sqrt(n).
When n is not a square, it is of course impossible for sqrt to produce an exact result. However, that is fine for your purpose, as the return value will be truncated, and the computed product will not equal n, so the comparison (int)std::sqrt(n)*(int)std::sqrt(n) == n will evaluate to false, as desired.
Where you have a problem is that some implementations of sqrt may not return an integer even when n is an integer square.
If you have a good sqrt implementation, it will return an exact result, and the comparison of the product with n will evaluate to true, as desired. If you have a bad sqrt implementation, and it returns a value slightly less than the proper square root of n, then the comparison will evaluate to false, causing a problem in your program.
Since you are only interested in the range up to 10,000, you can easily test sqrt on all squares in this range to see if it performs as desired.


Is it safe to assume 32-bit floats can be directly compared against each other if value fits the mantissa?

One way to determine if is not safe is to compare the results against a direct, non-performant reference code and look for differences.
If they all compare, then at least on one machine and compiler, it is safe to compare.
OP's code likely has trouble when int is 16-bit.
Below is some test code to compare.
/*
 * Return true if `n` is the sum of 2 perfect squares
 */
bool IsSumOf2Squares(int n, int *a_ptr, int *b_ptr) {
  if (n < 0) {
    return false;
  }
  int b_target;
  for (int a = 0; (b_target = n - a * a) >= 0; a++) {
    int diff;
    for (int b = a; (diff = b_target - b * b) >= 0; b++) {
      if (diff == 0) {
        *a_ptr = a;
        *b_ptr = b;
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

int main(void) {
  clock_t c0, c1;
  c0 = clock();
  int count = 0;
  int n = 10000;
  for (int i = -42; i <= n; i++) {
    int a, b;
    if (IsSumOf2Squares(i, &a, &b)) {
      if (count % 300 == 0) {
        printf("%10d: %5d %5d\n", i, a, b);
        fflush(stdout);
      }
      count++;
    }
  }
  c1 = clock();
  printf("Count: %d, Time:%gs\n", count, (double) (c1 - c0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  return 0;
}

Output
         0:     0     0
       901:     1    30
      1933:    13    42
      3001:    20    51
      4105:     3    64
      5213:    37    62
      6354:    27    75
      7489:    33    80
      8656:    40    84
      9808:    68    72
Count: 2750, Time:0.015s

